# Почему опросительные знаки вместо русских букв?

Tags: php

На странице нет подключения к БД, только этот код.

```
require_once(getenv('DOCUMENT_ROOT').'/simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('http://prime-music.net/Media-download-74244.html');
$a = $html->find('.font12');

echo $a[0]->innertext;

$html->clear();
unset($html);
```

Все что я нашел в интернете касается подключения к БД и ее неправильной кодировки, непонятно почему у меня так. Файл в UTF-8 без BOM.

Comment: зато страница, которую парсите `windows-1251`

Comment: А если в браузере ручками указываешь utf8 то показывается нормально ? )

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, что посоветуете?

Comment: Просто полученный контент переконвертируйте в ютф....через `iconv` к примеру

Comment: спасибо, выручили